# Best way to update android database(now i am using sugarORM)

Tags: android, database, sugarorm

The question is: I need to update my database each time the app runs, now i am doing it by deleting all old database records, and saving new records.

It works but is seeems to be realy bad realization, also it grows the database id's every time database been rewrited.

What is the best way to handle this task?

```
 private void loadData(){
        conMan = (ConnectivityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        netInfo = conMan.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Activities");

if (netInfo != null && netInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
            mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Action action;
                    Log.e("wifiState", netInfo.isConnected() + "");
                    Action.deleteAll(Action.class);
                    for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        action = child.getValue(Action.class);
                        action.save();
                        Log.e("saveData", action.getName());
                        Log.e("data", child.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }else{
            Log.e("noNet","quesy data from local database");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some unique key criteria in your tables. Once you again save updated record with same unique key, it will overwrite it in database. You need to update rather than 'delete and insert' everytime

Comment: I am getting data from noSQL database, but i yhink il just manualy add id field.

Comment: Yes in order to overwrite same record you will have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, according to you description, there are no needs to have the database in your application. If your data should be fully updated every time you start the app, then you can you implement simple caching algorythm with the lifecycle equaled to your app lifecycle.

Comment: I want to make it working offline also. So if i can't update it(no internet), i want too run it from local database(as it it was done in parce.com).